# celery over beanstalk broker: delays in task execution

Tags: python, celery, beanstalkd

**TL;DR:**

I'm queuing up short and simple tasks to `celeryd` via a `beanstalkd` broker, using `task.delay` (e.g. `myNotifyTask.delay()` instead of `myNotifyTask()`). Despite the fact the delay value is supposed to be immediate, tasks take around an hour to execute (when they should take mere seconds).

From my observations, it seems the tasks are indeed received in `beanstalkd`, but stay in a `ready` state for a very long time. This happens despite setting `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 8`. When viewing `beanstalkd`'s logs, I get errors about `read(): Connection reset by peer`, but the tasks do eventually execute.

Any ideas why this could happen?

Details below.

---

Using beanstalk version 1.4.6, celery 3.0.20.

The beanstalk log entries look like this:

```
/usr/bin/beanstalkd: prot.c:709 in check_err: read(): Connection reset by peer
```

When attempting to use `celery` to diagnose the problems:

```
> celery -b "beanstalk://beanstalk_server:11300" status
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

When connecting to `beanstalkd` via `telnet`, I see `current-jobs-ready: 343`, which suggests jobs are stuck in the `ready` state (not `delayed`). Here is the full output:

```
> telnet localhost 11300
stats
OK 850
---
current-jobs-urgent: 343
current-jobs-ready: 343
current-jobs-reserved: 0
current-jobs-delayed: 0
current-jobs-buried: 0
cmd-put: 2484
cmd-peek: 0
cmd-peek-ready: 7
cmd-peek-delayed: 1
cmd-peek-buried: 1
cmd-reserve: 0
cmd-reserve-with-timeout: 52941
cmd-delete: 2141
cmd-release: 0
cmd-use: 2485
cmd-watch: 42
cmd-ignore: 40
cmd-bury: 0
cmd-kick: 0
cmd-touch: 0
cmd-stats: 497655
cmd-stats-job: 2141
cmd-stats-tube: 3
cmd-list-tubes: 2
cmd-list-tube-used: 1
cmd-list-tubes-watched: 52954
cmd-pause-tube: 0
job-timeouts: 0
total-jobs: 2484
max-job-size: 65535
current-tubes: 3
current-connections: 6
current-producers: 2
current-workers: 2
current-waiting: 1
total-connections: 502958
pid: 989
version: 1.4.6
rusage-utime: 45.778861
rusage-stime: 56.595537
uptime: 2489047
binlog-oldest-index: 0
binlog-current-index: 0
binlog-max-size: 10485760
```

And shortly after:

```
stats-tube celery
OK 257
---
name: celery
current-jobs-urgent: 348
current-jobs-ready: 348
current-jobs-reserved: 0
current-jobs-delayed: 0
current-jobs-buried: 0
total-jobs: 2739
current-using: 3
current-watching: 1
current-waiting: 0
cmd-pause-tube: 0
pause: 0
pause-time-left: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that one celery task had a very long timeout, which caused its worker to wait for a long time. Even though concurrency was turned on, the timeouts were simply too long, and the tasks kept piling up in the beanstalk (without celery consuming them, since all the workers eventually get busy).